# How to build a jar in NetBeans 6.9?

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, ant

When I press "build project" it NetBeans builds, as far as I could find, separate class files. How can I set it to build them into a jar file? Even better it'd be if I can build several applications (all separately runnable from command line) from one project.

I code Scala 2.8.

Comment: Is this all in one project? For the second hope you will probably need use your own manifest.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Run > Clean and Build Main Project` command in  NetBeans puts your program's JAR in a folder named `dist` located at the root level of the project; any associated libraries go in `dist/lib`. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211980), a JAR's manifest may have only one `Main-Class` attribute, but the JAR itself may have an arbitrary number of classes that declare a `main()` method.

Addendum: Here is a concrete example using [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

```
$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools/Console -help
$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools/Server -help
$ java -cp h2.jar org.h2.tools/Shell -help
```

Addendum: External libraries are often added via the [Library Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976322).

Comment: Doesn't NetBeans use maven ? In this case, wouldn't the result be in the target folder ?

Comment: @Colin HEBERT: `maven` is one way NetBeans supports locating external dependencies; I added a link to a picture of the Library Manager above.